# How do I prove that an anti-symmetric matrix $A$ is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$A$ is a square anti symmetric matrix with dimension $n\times n$.

It is known that $n$ is an odd number. Prove that $A$ is not invertible.

How do I prove this? any hints please?

Answer (score 19):

$$\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)=-\det(A)$$ since $n$ is odd. hence $$\det(A)=0$$

Comment: I did not get it, why $$\det(A)=\det(A^T)$$ and why $$\det(A^T)=\det(-A)$$

Comment: because determinant of a matrix and determinant of its transpose are equal always.

Comment: antisymmetric means $A^T=-A$, by definition